# How to fix iPad Pro complaining about unsupported Apple Smart Keyboard?

Tags: ipad, keyboard

I'm using a Smart Keyboard with an iPad pro, but get a *Accessory not supported* error every 30 seconds. How can I fix this?

Comment: To what kind of device do you connect the keyboard to?

Comment: ipad pro 2.9 and the keyboard is original

Comment: Try this: https://macreports.com/ipad-pro-smart-keyboard-says-this-accessory-is-not-supported-by-this-device/

Comment: I've edited your question to focus more on fixing the issue, hope that's ok for you.

Answer (score 2):

The Smart Connector (three small pins) on the Apple Smart Keyboard is not forming a clean connection with the corresponding three-pin socket on the side of the iPad Pro.

Here are some ways to fix it:

1. Clean the contacts on the keyboard and iPad Pro
2. Remove the Keyboard, restart your iPad Pro, reconnect the keyboard

More info can be found on this Apple Support document:
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT205237

However, this technique worked for me (it is not mentioned on the Apple support site):

1. Remove the Smart Keyboard
2. Put your thumbs on the plastic ridge behind the contacts on the
   Smart Keyboard
3. Gently push the Smart Connector outwards with your thumb, and with your fingers pull the ends of the plastic ridge on Smart Keyboard towards you so it slightly bends the ridge (moving the smart connector outwards).
4. Reconnect the Smart Keyboard

I did this and it formed a better connection between the Smart Connector on the keyboard and iPad Pro.

This technique fixed my Smart Keyboard and prevented the "Accessory not supported" error from appearing.

Images here showing the push and bend in my keyboard:
https://www.flickr.com/gp/185452511@N03/m444o6

Comment: pull the two ends towards you - do you mean the three pins from the keyboard?

Comment: The two sides of the smart keyboard connector.

Comment: Have added a link to Flickr to help explain.

Comment: @LucyHattersley thank you! this was the clearest method and it worked for me. saved a lot of heartache.